# Solving $dX_{t}=X_{t}dt+dB_{t}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I want to solve the following stochastic differential equation

$dX_{t}=X_{t}dt+dB_{t}$ where $B_{t}$ is standard Brownian motion.

The hint to this exersice is to "multiply by $e^{-t}$ and compare with $d(e^{-t}X_{t})$"

Now when I follow these instructions I obtain $e^{-t}dX_{t}=e^{-t}X_{t}dt+e^{-t}dB_{t}$ and by Ito lemma I get $d(e^{-t}X_{t})=e^{-t}dB_{t}$. Combining this we get 
$e^{-t}dX_{t}=e^{-t}X_{t}dt+e^{-t}dB_{t}=e^{-t}X_{t}dt+d(e^{-t}X_{t})$

which is the same as,

$d(e^{-t}X_{t})=e^{-t}dX_{t}-e^{-t}X_{t}dt$ (but this is what Ito lemma gives aswell)

hence,

$X_{t}=e^{t}X_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}e^{t-s}dB_{s}$

But the twist is that so does just applying Ito formula on $X_{t}$ with $g(t,x)=e^{-t}x$ to obtain $d(e^{-t}X_{t})$ and then taking the integral.

Have I misunderstood this hint or is it confusing? Why dont he ju say use the Ito formula? Since I use what I already know from Ito lemma, $d(e^{-t}X_{t})=e^{-t}dB_{t}$ to do the last step.

Maybe he makes one does it like this since it is hard to find integrating factors in general. Applying Ito lemma might be much harder in general.

Update!
This guy seam to to have similar problems,

[If $dX_{t} = X_{t}\,dt + \,dB_{t}$, why does $e^{- t}dX_{t} = e^{-t} X_{t} \,dt + e^{-t} \,dB_{t}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647732/if-dx-t-x-t-dt-db-t-why-does-e-tdx-t-e-t-x-t-dt?rq=1)

Comment: "Now when I follow these instructions I obtain.." What tool did you use there to obtain what you obtained?

Comment: @Calculon added the details

Comment: Search for "linear SDE" ...

Comment: @saz where? Do you mean on google?

Comment: no, on stackexchange.

Comment: The point is that $d(e^{-t} X_t)=e^{-t}(dX_t-X_t dt)$. So multiplying both sides by $e^{-t}$ lets you rewrite the part of the equation involving $X_t$ as the differential of something. It's just like in elementary ODE, except with Ito terms floating around.

Comment: @Ian and both ways of solving is are legit?

Comment: It's not two ways, really. It's just checking that $d(e^{-t} X_t)$ actually has anything to do with the original SDE.

Comment: @Ian actually I think my first calculation is wrong integrating $d(e^{-t}X_{t})$ does not give $X_{0}$ as "integrating constant".

Comment: It's not supposed to. Integrating $d(e^{-t} X_t)$ gives $e^{-t} X_t - e^0 X_0$ (this has nothing to do with the given SDE). At the same time it gives $\int_0^t e^{-s} dB_s$ (which is where the SDE comes in). So you can do the algebra to solve for $X_t$.

Comment: @Ian sorry thats what I ment. It that really vaild?

Comment: Sure, once you check that $d(e^{-t} X_t)=e^{-t} dB_t$. You might want to review the integrating factor method for first order linear ODE, it goes the same way except that you use classical derivatives instead of stochastic differentials.

Comment: @Ian thus the "goal" is just to get the RHS to not include $X_{t}$ and and the LHS be $d(f(X_{t}))$ for some somewhat reasonable $f$. And it dosnt really matter how we get to this point.

Maybe he picked this hint to let one be able to genelise the idea to a more systematic approch. It might be hard to find the right $C^2$ function to apply Ito in general.

Comment: @Ian btw my confusion all boils down to which order one uses Ito lemma and "the shape" of $dX_{t}$

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the goal (though it is fine if $f$ also depends explicitly on $t$).